# Is there a way to use To Do Skill when you lack permission to add required scopes

Tags: botframework

When I run the **add_remote_skill.ps1** command I see the following warning message:

*"Could not configure scopes automatically. You must configure the following scopes in the Azure Portal to use this skill: Tasks.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite People.Read User.Read Contacts.Read"*

I lack the proper permissions to add scopes or modify the application registration for my To Do Skill.  Is there a way to use my personal hotmail/outlook account to work around not having permissions to add necessary scopes in my current tenant? If so, what are the steps to configure that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Manual Authentication Connection configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/howto/skills/addingskills.md#manual-authentication-connection-configuration) documentation, if a Skill requires Authentication connections to Office/Office 365, the PowerShell script will automatically add the required configuration to your Bot and associated Azure AD Application.

If your Azure AD application has allowed users outside of your tenant to access the application, then auto-provisioning isn't possible and the CLI will give a warning(the warning which you got above) that it wasn't able to configure Scopes and provides the Scopes you should manually add. Follow the instructions below to manually add the scopes:

- Find the Azure AD Application for your Bot within the Azure Portal.
- In the Authentication section ensure the Redirect Uri is set to `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`
- In the API permissions section click Add Permission, then Microsoft Graph and Delegated Permissions. Find each scope provided in the message shown during Skill registration and add.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, then can you please accept this so that it helps other?